# Guidance on Data Scaling for LSTM Autoencoder

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, normalization, feature-engineering

I'm working with a dataset of 9 features. While 8 of them have values ranging from 0-255, one feature has significantly different values. I'm using this dataset with an LSTM autoencoder for anomaly detection and had a couple of questions about scaling:

Although RobustScaler is recommended for handling outliers, I found that StandardScaler outperforms it in my tests. Could you explain why this might be the case?

I experimented with using RobustScaler for the divergent feature and StandardScaler for the rest. This approach seemed promising. Would you recommend this hybrid scaling method, or should I stick to one scaler for all features?

I'd appreciate your insights and guidance on the best approach.

Thank you for your time and expertise.